# Custom WordPress Post Type: Maintain Hierarchy but Remove Parent Slug from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

I have a custom WordPress post type called 'produktseiten', and I'm using a custom rewrite slug 'c'. Each post of this type is assigned a parent post, and this is reflected in the URL structure.

For example, the URL for a 'produktseiten' post would look like this:

https://www.example.com/c/parent-post/post-name/

What I want is to remove the parent slug from the URL while maintaining the hierarchy within the WordPress structure (for breadcrumbs and other purposes). So, the URL should look like this:

https://www.example.com/c/post-name/

I tried using the following code snippet:

```
function remove_parent_slug($link, $post) {
    if ('produktseiten' == $post->post_type && $post->post_parent) {
        $link = home_url(user_trailingslashit("c/" . $post->post_name));
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'remove_parent_slug', 10, 2);

function parse_request_tricksy($query) {
    if (! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count($query->query) || ! isset($query->query['page'])) {
        return;
    }
    if (! empty($query->query['name'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'produktseiten', 'page'));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'parse_request_tricksy');
```

But this leads to a 404 error when trying to access the URL https://www.example.com/c/post-name/. It seems like WordPress is not able to correctly find the post when the parent slug is missing. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this question and answer is what you are looking for: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214599/12496